# Rails - Has_many with one option selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails application that answers some survery questions.  It's for an experiment on selecting trade-offs though, and for each question many of the answers are generated dynamically.  So I need to keep records for not only which answer was selected for each question, but also what each of the options were that were presented to the User.

So, my models are

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :questions
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey
  has_many :possible_answers
end

class PossibleAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

From here, what's the best practice for keeping track of which PossibleAnswer was selected?  And indicator withing the PossibleAnswer model, and then validation logic to check that only one was selected?  Or should I redefine a the relationships within my Question so that I `have_many` RejectedAnswers and `have_one` AcceptedAnswer?

I know that there are multiple ways to do this, but I'm trying to understand which option would generally be considered the best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd add accepted_answer_id to Question and have it point to a PossibleAnswer.